# Replace hidden value in a form with javascript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm working with Google Checkout and am creating a simple Buy Now button. The button will be on many pages and have many values for the form.

What I'm looking to do is to use Javascript, to get a value on a text_field, and replace a hidden field value.

To get the value, I have this code:

```
$('#payment_quantity input').keyup(function() {
    var quantity = $('#payment_quantity input').val();
    return false;
});
```

Then, in the form from google, I have this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_quantity_1" value="1"/>
```

What I need to be able to do, is replace the value on this hidden input, with my quantity variable. I know this is probably really easy, but I'm amazingly confused at how to do this. I should have to select the hidden field, but I don't know how to update the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to construct a jQuery selector to get that field and then use the `.val(xxx)` method to set its value.

jQuery loves to overload the same method for different behaviors based on what you pass as arguments.  In the case of `.val()`, if you pass no arguments, it retrieves the field value.  If you pass an argument like `.val(quantity)`, it sets that value into the field like this:

```
$('#payment_quantity input').keyup(function() {
    var quantity = $('#payment_quantity input').val();
    $("input[name='item_quantity_1']").val(quantity);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here ya go:

```
$('input[name="item_quantity_1"]').val(quantity);
```